# How would you write this in Sigma notation

Tags: summation

I stumbled upon this expression:$$p_nq_mx^{m+n}+(p_{n-1}q_m+p_nq_{m-1})x^{m+n-1}+(p_{n-2}q_m+p_{n-1}q_{m-1}+p_nq_{m-2})x^{m+n-2}+\ldots+p_0q_0\tag1$$
And I'm wondering if there is an easier way to represent $(1)$ using the sum notation Sigma: $\sum$.

Comment: Are you sure the last term $p_0q_0$ is correct? It doesn't seem to match up with the rest.

Comment: @AlexR. Yes, I'm $100\%$ sure...

Comment: sure it does, $x^{0+0}=1$

Comment: That would be the $x^m$ term which is somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{m} p_iq_jx^{i+j}$$

Comment: Cool, good enough! Thanks!